# back office prestashop déconexion

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I installed Prestashop 1.7 for an end-of-study project but I found a problem when using it.

Every time I connect to the back office and make changes the application logs off and redirects me to the authentication page. I have researched the problem and found it has a relationship with cookies so I deleted the IP address check but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

When you login to the admin panel, then on the login form there is a checkbox named 'Stay logged in', just check is while logging in and it will fix your problem. Please check attached screenshot for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug which happened also to me

Edit the file :

> your_admin_folder/themes/default/template/controllers/login/content.tpl

and add the

```
style="position: relative;
```

to the formgroup in line 77

```
<div class="form-group" style="position: relative;">
                        <div id="remind-me" class="checkbox pull-left">
...
```